# I have a textfield time input and I want to change dropdown list color from blue to red on select

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI `Textfield` time input and I want to change dropdown list color from blue to red on select. For example, I want to change the dropdown select of blue to red.

I'm using Material UI in ReactJS.

Here is the image:

[image]

```
<TextField
  id="time"
  type="time"
  style={{
    width: "148px",
    marginLeft: 4,
    marginRight: 6,
    padding: "2px 0px 3px 6px",
  }}
  defaultValue="07:30"
  iconComponent={ExpandMoreIcon}
  className={classes.textField}
  color="secondary"
  InputProps={{
    disableUnderline: true,
    endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon />,
    // className: classes.input,
  }}
/>;
```

I want to change the dropdown list color on select from blue to red.

Is there a way to change it??

Comment: The `TextField` component with the `type="time"` is just a native `<input type="time">` HTML element. Sadly it's almost impossible to customise native element because they depend on the browser that is used.

Comment: Is there a way to customize this in material-ui?? Like on hover in list can you change the color to red or gray??

Comment: `Sadly it's almost impossible to customise native element because they depend on the browser that is used.`. So no I will discourage you to try to update the native aspect of this element and rather use another component like the [date picker](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/) that is powered by some JavaScript and will mostly render the same on all devives.